# Can the ordinary android view extend with GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, view, extends, glsurfaceview

I am trying to use the GLSurfaceView to draw image in my android ordinary view.
But I heard that the a view can't extends other view.
Really, Can I do this?

Comment: That's a limit of java. You can't extend two classes at the same time, but since GLSurfaceView extends View, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem), the Java language only allows you to extend one class.